# Make text responsive to whether its overflows its parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

How can I ensure text adjusts its font-size to keep it from overflowing a static, 50px, navbar?

I have a preliminary script, but it doesn't really do the trick. It only adjusts the pixels by 1px for every browser resize, and that doesn't even take into account if someone goes directly to mobile:

```
          window.onresize = function(){    
            var title = document.getElementById('testing');             
            var style = window.getComputedStyle(title, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
            var fontSize = parseFloat(style);  
            if(title.scrollHeight > 51){
              title.style.fontSize = (fontSize - 0.5) + 'px';
              $(title).height(50);
            } else if (title.scrollHeight < 51) {
              title.style.fontSize = (fontSize + 0.5) + 'px';
              $(title).height(50);
            }
          };
```

Comment: A more solid approach would be using CSS mediaqueries and having a mobile safe layout for your navbar.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do, so does your Nav size changes base on screen size or it's always 50 x 50?
So do you basically want your text to 'fill up' the whole Nav base on it's size?

Comment: @NaturalLam, the Nav size stays at 50px, but an inner div's text changes based on database content. Therefore, if the content is too long, the content will overflow and cause that div's height to exceed 50px. The Nav's overflow is hidden, so this content is only partially visible. For these reasons, I don't think mere CSS will work because the initial size of the text should also be responsive to the length of text in in this inner div.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS...

```
#testing{
    font-size:1.5vw
}
```

? - Change value accordingly of course

Comment: the problem with that becomes clear when you rotate a tablet or fullscreen a window to a different aspect ratio. to wit: a narrowing window will yield tiny text too quickly as it's "shrunk down"...

Comment: Yes but thats then when you'd use @media orientation queries to change the value to ems maybe? Just a thought

Comment: Yes, it becomes problematic with varying screen ratios only because our navbar is hardcoded to stay at `50px.` Maybe the answer would be to write an algorithm that accounts for height to width ratio of the navbar itself rather than the screen.

Comment: In other words, the ratio of words to div dimensions can and should change to keep it readable.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a jQuery solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/dsunr5px/1/

It will reduce the size of the text incrementally until it fits within its parent:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

adjustWidth();

jQuery(window).onresize(adjustWidth());

function adjustWidth() {

    jQuery(".text").each(function() {
        var width = jQuery(this).width();

        while(width <= jQuery(this).children().width() )
        {
            var fontsize = parseInt(jQuery(this).children().css('font-size'));
            var newfs = fontsize - 1 + 'px';
            jQuery(this).children().css({'font-size': newfs}); 
        }
    });
}

});
```

But, as you can see, it can get a little crazy. A line break would be more user friendly, generally speaking. You might be able to put some more logic in there to determine at what point going too small is too small and it should just do a line break. The industry standard for solving responsive problems, though, is always media queries. Unless you have a driving reason not to, I would investigate a solution in that direction.

Comment: I'll give this a shot tomorrow. The reason why I'm not using media queries, and this may be ill-informed, is that the breakpoints will differ depending on the user's unique content for this title section. ( I will note that we're using Foundation, and this section is wrapped up as a column. )

Comment: Would a line break be acceptable? As in, if the text goes past the width of the column, it breaks at a word to the next row.

If so, just make sure the text has the css property display:inline and its parent has the property display:block.

Comment: Oh - I see. I wasn't that clear. My div is overflowing it's parent navbar vertically, not horizontally. The text isn't overflowing. The div's height increases, and the text stays inside, but the I need the height to stay at 50px and have the text adjust their font-size before overflowing the 50px div...if that isn't confusing enough!

Comment: The solution I gave in this answer measures against width, but the fiddle example shows how it can get way too small if too much text is put in too small a place. It may satisfy your requirements, but my own experience here has always lead me to force the design to accept a variable height so that dynamic text is always readable. User experience first, design second.